# click on element with same class and remove property from previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have structure like this

```
<div class='row'>
  <span class="fake-label"></span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <span class="fake-label"></span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <span class="fake-label"></span>
</div>
```

when i click at any 'fake-label' jquery code is evaluate

```
$('span.fake-label').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.row').addClass('bet-popup-active');
        $(this).parents('.row').find('.popup-bet').removeClass('js-slide-hidden');
        $(this).parents('.row').find('.popup-bet').fadeIn(300).css('display','block');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.input-bet > input').focus();
        },5);
    });
```

the problem is that i can't figure out how on click at other 'fake-label' remove jquery code from clicked 'fake-label' before.

Comment: Do you want to execute your code one time ?

Comment: To target them, you could use `$('.row').not($(this).closest('.row'))`. Then inverse your logic on it, e.g: `$('.row').not($(this).closest('.row')).removeClass('bet-popup-active').addClass('js-slide-hidden');`. If you want to animate it, then use `fadeOut()` on them and remove/add classes in complete callback.

Comment: you could give the previous element a unique id, and retrieve it using this id with `try{}catch(err){}`, otherwise just store the previous element in a global variable to use later.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH no, i need execute it every time if click at other 'fake-label'

Comment: I don't see how that click function is being invoked as `fake-label` are not a direct child of `label` in your code. The are a direct child of `div`

Comment: @TheMintyMate every clicked 'row' element get dinamics added 'bet-popup-active' class

Comment: @wmash previous selector is form prod version, forget to adapt if for this example

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks a lot, fighting with this problem about 5 days. I take off my hat to you)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this is what you are looking for:

```
$('span.fake-label').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.popup-bet').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('js-slide-hidden');
    });
    $(this).parents('.row').addClass('bet-popup-active');
});
```

Just remove the class from every element and then add the new one to the clicked.

[.each() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the click event to be fired once per element you should use [**one()** method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) :

```
  $('label > span.fake-label').one( "click", function() {
    $(this).parents('.row').addClass('bet-popup-active');
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.popup-bet').removeClass('js-slide-hidden');
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.popup-bet').fadeIn(300).css('display','block');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.input-bet > input').focus();
    },5);
  });
```

Comment: it's work the same way. I need remove class which i add when i click next element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but if you want to delete the code you wrote in an "onclick" function for an element, you can do it like this:

```
$('.element').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

Comment: I didn't know about this method, thanks. That should work too.